# Search bar in vuetify's v-select component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify's v-select component. I am trying to add a search bar option in the dropdown.

Is there any inbuilt way I can do that. I am using vuetify version 1.0.5.

```
    <v-select
     :items="users"
     attach
     item-text='name'
     item-value='name'
     v-model="association.name"
     :rules='nameRule'
     label="First Name"
     required>
    </v-select>
```

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like you're looking for [`v-autocomplete`](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes).

Vuetify 1.0.5 seems extremely out of date (current version: 1.5.24 / 2.2.20), you should update if you can.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add a template slot and write custom search logic. I have created a code pen for the same. Please alter it to your needs.

```
<template v-slot:prepend-item>
  <v-list-item>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-text-field v-model="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" @input="searchFruits"></v-text-field>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
  <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
</template>

// method
searchFruits (e) {
  if (!this.searchTerm) {
    this.fruits = this.fruitsCopy;
  }

  this.fruits = this.fruitsCopy.filter(fruit => {
    return fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1
  })
}
```

https://codepen.io/sudheer-ranga/pen/bGVbjbx

Comment: This is a great idea, but carries a huge inconvenient: The search bar will scroll with the rest of the items. Using the prepend-item slot will just implement an extra item before all the other items (you can clearly style or doing different things) but it is and it will remain an item. In order to have the search bar has fixed header, and the items able to scroll under it, you must remove it from the item flow. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to exist a simple way to do so.

Comment: @Dinuz did you get a solution to this (search scroll with rest items)?  I was looking for the same and even the latest vuetify doesn't seem to provide a slot.